# Getting an error with a DLL injector in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a DLL injector.  A really simple one: console app, input DLL, input process.  But I'm getting an error on line 26:

```
LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
```

Can someone help me?

```
#include<Windows.h> //DWORD
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <psapi.h> //EnumProcessModules
#include <VersionHelpers.h>
#include <atlstr.h> // CString

#define CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS (PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ)

BOOL InjectDLL(DWORD ProcessID)
{
    LPCSTR DLL_PATH = "dll file here";
    LPVOID LoadLibAddy, RemoteString;

    if (!ProcessID)
        return false;

    HANDLE Proc = OpenProcess(CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);

    if (!Proc)
    {
        std::cout << "OpenProcess() failed: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

    RemoteString = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(Proc, NULL, strlen(DLL_PATH) + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(Proc, RemoteString, (LPVOID)DLL_PATH, strlen(DLL_PATH)+1, NULL);
    CreateRemoteThread(Proc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddy, RemoteString, NULL, NULL);

    CloseHandle(Proc);

    return true;
...
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: Could you tell us the detailed error you are getting?Is it a compilation error or a runtime error, and what the specific error message is.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what kind of error you are getting.  But I suspect you are getting a compile-time error on `GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll")`.  If your project is set to use the Unicode character set, you would need to use `GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll")` instead.  Or better, since `GetModuleHandle()` is a `TCHAR`-based macro, use `TEXT("kernel32.dll")` to match:

```cpp
LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "LoadLibraryA");
```

Otherwise, use `GetModuleHandleA()` or `GetModuleHandleW()` instead:

```cpp
LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
```

```cpp
LoadLibAddy = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
```

That being said, you are also not doing any error handling when allocating memory or creating the remote thread.  And your logic is incomplete as you are leaking allocated memory and resources. You need to wait for the remote thread to finish, and then free the virtual memory you allocate, and close the handle to the thread.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h> //DWORD
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <psapi.h> //EnumProcessModules
#include <VersionHelpers.h>
#include <atlstr.h> // CString

#define CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS (PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ)

bool InjectDLL(DWORD ProcessID)
{
    LPCSTR DLL_PATH = "dll file here";
    int DLL_PATH_SIZE = strlen(DLL_PATH) + 1;

    if (ProcessID == 0)
        return false;

    FARPROC LoadLibAddy = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (!LoadLibAddy)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Can't find LoadLibraryA: " << err << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    HANDLE Proc = OpenProcess(CREATE_THREAD_ACCESS, FALSE, ProcessID);
    if (!Proc)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "OpenProcess() failed: " << err << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    LPVOID RemoteString = VirtualAllocEx(Proc, NULL, DLL_PATH_SIZE, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!RemoteString)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "VirtualAllocEx() failed: " << err << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(Proc);
        return false;
    }

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(Proc, RemoteString, DLL_PATH, DLL_PATH_SIZE, NULL))
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "WriteProcessMemory() failed: " << err << std::endl;
        VirtualFreeEx(Proc, RemoteString, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(Proc);
        return false;
    }

    HANDLE Thread = CreateRemoteThread(Proc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddy, RemoteString, NULL, NULL);
    if (!Thread)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "CreateRemoteThread() failed: " << err << std::endl;
        VirtualFreeEx(Proc, RemoteString, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(Proc);
        return false;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(Thread, INFINITE);

    // If the target process is 32bit, you can use GetExitCodeThread()
    // to find out if LoadLibraryA() was successful or not.
    //
    // If the target process is 64bit, it is much harder to determine
    // that. You would have to allocate an entire function containing
    // shellcode that calls LoadLibraryA() and saves the result in
    // memory that you can then read via ReadProcessMemory().  Or,
    // you would have to enumerate the target process's modules list
    // looking for the DLL that you just injected.

    CloseHandle(Thread);

    VirtualFreeEx(Proc, RemoteString, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(Proc);

    return true;
}
```